# Permission Denied on editing .bash_profile?

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to set adb path so I can access it easily from any directory.To set the path I am trying to edit the `.bash_profile` to insert the following line :

> export PATH=$PATH:/Users/anshulsinghla/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/

**Command I use to open file:** `open -e .bash_profile`

But I always get a prompt saying "*You Don't own the file .bash_profile and don't have permission to write to it. You can duplicate this document and edit the duplicate.Only the duplicate will include your changes*".

I tried checking the who is the owner and what permission do they have with following command :

> ls -la ~ | grep bash

Output:

> -rw-------    1 anshulsinghla  staff    6820 Jun 22 10:09 .bash_history
>
> -rw-r--r--    1 anshulsinghla  staff     659 Jun 22 10:11 .bash_profile

It clearly shows I am the owner of the file and I do have read/write permissions but why it never let me edit the file, someone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Who are member of group `staff`?

Comment: Are you somehow not the owner of your own home directory? Try `ls -ld ~` and see what it shows.

Comment: @GordonDavisson drwxr-xr-x+ 29 anshulsinghla  staff  986 Jun  8 23:20 /Users/anshulsinghla

Comment: Could you please show the output of `ls -l@ ~ | grep bash` and `id`

Comment: @Paul -rw-r-----@   1 anshulsinghla  staff   56968 Dec 17  2015 git-completion.bash

Comment: How exactly do you edit `.bash_profile` that you get this error? I mean what editor do you use and if it's console editor how do you run it?

Comment: @Paul TextEdit, I just type open -e .bash_profile

Comment: Could you also please show the output of `id`.

Comment: @Paul What do you mean by id?

Comment: @user818455 No, just execute the command `id` in shell

Comment: ^^ `id` is a command (`/usr/bin/id`). You can run `id` on terminal...

Comment: @Paul uid=501(anshulsinghla) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)

Comment: I'm puzzled by the error message *I am not the owner of this file and I can only duplicate it and not edit it*.  Could you please paste the **exact** command and error message into your question please?  This is because I tried to reproduce this (on OS X) and got a different message.  The other obvious thing is, what is your current directory when you try to edit?

Comment: @cdarke I have edited my question with the details your asked. Also the current directory when I try to edit is "anshulsinghla"

Comment: OK, I would have expected the current directory to be `/Users/anshulsinghla`, not just `anshulsinghla`.  All the diagnostics have been using `~`, so try `open -e ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @cdarke It worked.Thanks a lot, can you post this as an answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: @user818455:  glad it worked.  Answer posted,  have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the diagnostics have been using ~, so try:

```
open -e ~/.bash_profile
```

What did we learn from this?  When diagnosing an error, always use *exactly* the same filename as was used in the error.

The original command did not try to edit `.bash_profile` in your home directory, yet in the comments everyone was looking at your home directory.